# Image Processing with Three.js With Effect Composer

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, post-processing

Looking at the example here: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing

I'm curious if there is a way to perform this post-processing business on a copy of the original data set. In other words, I want to display the original rendering of my scene in one container, and then would like to display the post-processed scene in another container. How is this done?

Thanks!

Comment: Re-using data: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_advanced

Comment: I added answer, so it's easier for other users to see it and you can accept answer so we don't confuse others that land onto this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take a look at this example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_advanced

Generally, you render to a offscreen texture (not to the actual screen) and then use that as input texture for any other effect/primitive/whatever that you need to.